# Can existing types be extended to work with Seq.sum, etc?

Tags: f#

Been working with a lot of TimeSpans recently, and have a need to get sums & averages.
However, TimeSpan defines neither operator get_Zero nor DivideByInt, so Seq.sum and Seq.average can't be used directly with this type.  The following fails to compile:

```
open System
type System.TimeSpan
    with
        static member Zero with get() = TimeSpan()
        static member (/) (n:DateTime, d:int) = DateTime( n.Ticks / (int64) d )

let ts = [ TimeSpan(10L); TimeSpan(99L) ]
let sum = ts |> Seq.sum
let avg = ts |> Seq.average
```

- Error: The type 'TimeSpan' does not support any operators named 'get_Zero'
- Error: The type 'TimeSpan' does not support any operators named 'DivideByInt'
- Warning: Extension members cannot provide operator overloads.  Consider defining the operator as part of the type definition instead.

Is there some F# magic that can define these operators on an existing type?

I know the following will work (and should be more efficient to boot), but I'm still curious about the above so I can add it to my toolbox for use with other types.

```
let sum = TimeSpan( ts |> Seq.sumBy (fun t -> t.Ticks) )
let avg = TimeSpan( let len = ts |> Seq.length in sum.Ticks / int64 len )
```

Comment: `System.TimeSpan` is Sealed so you can't inherit from it either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, static member constraints (that are used by functions like `Seq.sum`) are not able to discover members that are added by type extensions (essentially, extension methods), so I don't think there is a direct way of doing this.

The best option I can think of is to creat a simple wrapper around the `System.TimeSpan` struct. Then you can define all the required members. The code would look like this:

```
[<Struct>]
type TimeSpan(ts:System.TimeSpan) =
  member x.TimeSpan = ts
  new(ticks:int64) = TimeSpan(System.TimeSpan(ticks))
  static member Zero = TimeSpan(System.TimeSpan.Zero)
  static member (+) (a:TimeSpan, b:TimeSpan) = 
    TimeSpan(a.TimeSpan + b.TimeSpan)
  static member DivideByInt (n:TimeSpan, d:int) = 
    TimeSpan(n.TimeSpan.Ticks / (int64 d)) 

let ts = [ TimeSpan(10L); TimeSpan(99L) ] 
let sum = ts |> Seq.sum 
let avg = ts |> Seq.average
```

I called the type `TimeSpan`, so it hides the standard `System.TimeSpan` type. However, you still need to write `ts.TimeSpan` when you need to access the underlying system type, so this isn't as nice as it could be.

Comment: So, the short answers is "you can't do it directly, but can do it via a proxy object."  That works for me.  As I said, this is no big deal for the current problem, but nice to have in my pocket.  Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed something.... looks like System.TimeSpan already does have a static read-only property called "Zero".  Any clue why F# complains that there is no such thing?

Comment: @James: I believe that `Zero` in `System.TimeSpan` is actually a field - not a property - and F# member constraints work with properties/methods only. A real-life example showing that using fields can cause troubles...!

Answer (score 3):

Mhh the following is rather ugly, but it works. Does it help? I define a wrapper for `TimeSpan` that can implicitly be converted back to a `TimeSpan`.

```
type MyTimeSpan(ts : TimeSpan) =
    member t.op_Implicit : TimeSpan = ts
    static member (+) (t1 : MyTimeSpan, t2 : MyTimeSpan) =
        new MyTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromTicks(t1.op_Implicit.Ticks + t2.op_Implicit.Ticks))
    static member Zero = new MyTimeSpan(TimeSpan.Zero)
    static member DivideByInt (t : MyTimeSpan, i : int) =
        new MyTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromTicks(int64 (float t.op_Implicit.Ticks / float i)))

let toMyTS ts = new MyTimeSpan(ts)

let l = [TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.)]
            |> List.map toMyTS
            |> List.average
```

Comment: Does the implicit conversion actually give you anything? As far as I know, F# ignores them (it doesn't do any implicit conversions), so this would be useful only if the type was used from C# too...